# Hi I would like to copy content of a canvas in another canvas with zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

Actually. I have created two canvas one containing some static content & over that another canvas containing some dynamic content. Now I have show snap of both the canvas with zoom in a separate canvas where the snap will change according to the moving object. I am using getImage & putImage but unable to zoom the image content. Even getImage is not working for the canvas contating dynamic content because security error is showing.

Comment: Post the code you wrote please !

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. The security thing is because the image isn't hosted on your domain, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.drawImage` can use another canvas as its source image.

`context.drawImage` can scale the source image when drawing.

`context.drawImage` does not run afoul of CORS security like `getImageData` does.

For example, assume sourceCanvas has the original image located at coordinate[20,30] sized at 100x140.

If you have a context to the destination canvas, you can scale it 2X and draw it on the destination canvas at [50,60] like this:

```
context.drawImage( 
    sourceCanvas,
    20,30,100,140,   // grabs 100x140 pixels from sourceCanvas at [20,30]
    50,60,200,280    // scale the grabbed pixels to 200x280 and draw it at [50,60]
);
```